# On Appetize.io app does not send analytic events to Firebase debugView

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

We have Firebase Crashlytics logging on the app. I am trying to log events to Firebase as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview). Also manifest contains:

```xml
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
            tools:node="remove" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="true"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
```

On appetize.io there is ssh tunnel, so I can remotely connect via `adb`. When running `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.my.app` I expect live events to show up on Firebase, which does not happen.

Here are the logs from the Appetize via their adb tunnel:

```
❯ adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
  adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
  adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
--------- beginning of main
10-28 05:00:20.671 I/FA      ( 1924): App measurement disabled by setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
10-28 05:00:20.672 I/FA      ( 1924): App measurement initialized, version: 28015
10-28 05:00:20.672 I/FA      ( 1924): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:20.672 I/FA      ( 1924): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:20.672 I/FA      ( 1924):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
10-28 05:00:21.239 I/FA-SVC  ( 1294): App measurement initialized, version: 212423
10-28 05:00:22.785 W/FA-SVC  ( 1294): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.apps.maps, 1666918822785, 1636602805328
10-28 05:00:23.947 I/FA      ( 1830): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:00:23.947 I/FA      ( 1830): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:23.947 I/FA      ( 1830): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:23.947 I/FA      ( 1830):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
10-28 05:00:23.976 I/FA      ( 1830): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
10-28 05:00:23.986 I/FA      ( 2735): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:00:23.986 I/FA      ( 2735): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:23.986 I/FA      ( 2735): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:23.986 I/FA      ( 2735):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging
10-28 05:00:24.862 I/FA      ( 1942): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:00:24.862 I/FA      ( 1942): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:24.862 I/FA      ( 1942): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:24.862 I/FA      ( 1942):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube
10-28 05:00:31.955 I/FA      ( 3615): App measurement disabled by setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
10-28 05:00:31.955 I/FA      ( 3615): App measurement initialized, version: 28015
10-28 05:00:31.955 I/FA      ( 3615): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:31.955 I/FA      ( 3615): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:31.955 I/FA      ( 3615):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
10-28 05:00:38.669 I/FA      ( 4175): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:00:38.669 I/FA      ( 4175): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:38.669 I/FA      ( 4175): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:38.669 I/FA      ( 4175):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube
10-28 05:00:44.960 I/FA-SVC  ( 1094): App measurement initialized, version: 212423
10-28 05:00:51.372 I/FA      ( 4626): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:00:51.372 I/FA      ( 4626): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:00:51.372 I/FA      ( 4626): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:00:51.372 I/FA      ( 4626):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging
10-28 05:01:23.688 I/FA      ( 5468): App measurement disabled by setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
10-28 05:01:23.689 I/FA      ( 5468): App measurement initialized, version: 28015
10-28 05:01:23.689 I/FA      ( 5468): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:01:23.689 I/FA      ( 5468): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:01:23.689 I/FA      ( 5468):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
10-28 05:01:29.271 I/FA      ( 5611): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:01:29.271 I/FA      ( 5611): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:01:29.271 I/FA      ( 5611): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:01:29.271 I/FA      ( 5611):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube
10-28 05:01:29.312 I/FA-SVC  ( 5882): App measurement initialized, version: 212423
10-28 05:01:29.540 I/FA-SVC  ( 5882): Install Referrer Reporter is not available
10-28 05:01:32.590 I/FA      ( 5818): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 05:01:32.590 I/FA      ( 5818): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 05:01:32.590 I/FA      ( 5818): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 05:01:32.590 I/FA      ( 5818):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
10-28 05:01:32.618 I/FA-SVC  ( 5882): Install Referrer Reporter is not available
10-28 05:01:35.729 I/FA-SVC  ( 5832): App measurement initialized, version: 212423
10-28 05:01:45.440 W/FA-SVC  ( 5882): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, 1666918905440, 1636602615899
10-28 05:01:45.519 W/FA-SVC  ( 5882): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.youtube, 1666918905519, 1636601698965
10-28 16:27:54.843 I/FA      ( 7296): App measurement disabled by setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
10-28 16:27:54.860 I/FA      ( 7296): App measurement initialized, version: 28015
10-28 16:27:54.860 I/FA      ( 7296): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 16:27:54.860 I/FA      ( 7296): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 16:27:54.860 I/FA      ( 7296):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
10-28 16:27:55.996 I/FA      ( 6908): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 16:27:55.996 I/FA      ( 6908): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 16:27:55.996 I/FA      ( 6908): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 16:27:55.996 I/FA      ( 6908):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging
10-28 16:27:56.055 I/FA-SVC  ( 5882): Install Referrer Reporter is not available
10-28 16:27:56.595 W/FA-SVC  ( 5882): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.apps.messaging, 1666960076595, 1636601717426
10-28 16:50:56.089 I/FA      ( 8871): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 16:50:56.089 I/FA      ( 8871): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 16:50:56.089 I/FA      ( 8871): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 16:50:56.089 I/FA      ( 8871):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.my.app.staging
10-28 16:50:56.994 I/FA-SVC  ( 8546): App measurement initialized, version: 212423
10-28 16:50:57.070 I/FA      ( 8871): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
10-28 16:50:57.271 I/FA-SVC  ( 8546): Install Referrer Reporter is not available
10-28 16:50:57.296 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:50:57.402 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:50:57.450 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:50:57.630 I/FA      ( 9171): App measurement disabled by setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
10-28 16:50:57.653 I/FA      ( 9171): App measurement initialized, version: 28015
10-28 16:50:57.653 I/FA      ( 9171): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 16:50:57.653 I/FA      ( 9171): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 16:50:57.653 I/FA      ( 9171):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
10-28 16:50:59.244 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:50:59.244 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:50:59.273 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:51:02.879 I/FA      ( 9572): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 16:51:02.879 I/FA      ( 9572): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 16:51:02.879 I/FA      ( 9572): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 16:51:02.879 I/FA      ( 9572):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube
10-28 16:51:04.060 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:04.069 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:11.434 I/FA      ( 9059): App measurement initialized, version: 42041
10-28 16:51:11.434 I/FA      ( 9059): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-28 16:51:11.434 I/FA      ( 9059): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-28 16:51:11.434 I/FA      ( 9059):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging
10-28 16:51:38.799 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:40.534 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:42.528 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:43.550 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:43.625 V/FA      ( 8871): Recording user engagement, ms: 39549
10-28 16:51:43.637 V/FA      ( 8871): Connecting to remote service
10-28 16:51:43.643 V/FA      ( 8871): Activity paused, time: 1563702
10-28 16:51:43.643 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:43.659 V/FA      ( 8871): onActivityCreated
10-28 16:51:43.729 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:43.738 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:43.744 V/FA      ( 8871): Activity resumed, time: 1563822
10-28 16:51:43.746 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:43.746 V/FA      ( 8871): Connection attempt already in progress
10-28 16:51:43.789 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:51:43.795 D/FA      ( 8871): Connected to remote service
10-28 16:51:43.806 V/FA      ( 8871): Processing queued up service tasks: 2
10-28 16:51:46.333 V/FA      ( 8871): Recording user engagement, ms: 2585
10-28 16:51:46.334 V/FA      ( 8871): Activity paused, time: 1566412
10-28 16:51:46.334 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:46.339 V/FA      ( 8871): onActivityCreated
10-28 16:51:46.451 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:46.453 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:46.492 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:46.495 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:46.495 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:46.495 W/FA      ( 8871): Cannot log screen view event when the app is in the background.
10-28 16:51:46.501 V/FA      ( 8871): Activity resumed, time: 1566581
10-28 16:51:46.505 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:46.562 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:51:46.673 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: SupportRequestManagerFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:51:46.674 V/FA      ( 8871): Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 172
10-28 16:51:46.706 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:51.728 V/FA      ( 8871): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
10-28 16:51:57.453 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:57.492 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:51:57.493 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: ConnectTabFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:51:57.496 V/FA      ( 8871): Recording user engagement, ms: 10992
10-28 16:51:57.499 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:57.499 V/FA      ( 8871): Connecting to remote service
10-28 16:51:57.522 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:51:57.532 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: ConnectionsFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:51:57.533 V/FA      ( 8871): Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 38
10-28 16:51:57.545 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:51:57.546 V/FA      ( 8871): Connection attempt already in progress
10-28 16:51:57.553 D/FA      ( 8871): Connected to remote service
10-28 16:51:57.554 V/FA      ( 8871): Processing queued up service tasks: 2
10-28 16:52:02.555 V/FA      ( 8871): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
10-28 16:52:44.154 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:52:44.176 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:52:44.181 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: AccountFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:52:44.182 V/FA      ( 8871): Recording user engagement, ms: 46688
10-28 16:52:44.186 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:52:44.186 V/FA      ( 8871): Connecting to remote service
10-28 16:52:44.227 D/FA      ( 8871): Connected to remote service
10-28 16:52:44.227 V/FA      ( 8871): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
10-28 16:52:49.228 V/FA      ( 8871): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
10-28 16:54:31.718 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.752 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: ProfileViewerFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:54:31.754 V/FA      ( 8871): Recording user engagement, ms: 107571
10-28 16:54:31.756 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.759 V/FA      ( 8871): Connecting to remote service
10-28 16:54:31.772 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.798 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: ProfileFieldsFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:54:31.799 V/FA      ( 8871): Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 46
10-28 16:54:31.802 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.802 V/FA      ( 8871): Connection attempt already in progress
10-28 16:54:31.811 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.816 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:54:31.819 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: NoticeboardLandingFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:54:31.820 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.823 V/FA      ( 8871): Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 67
10-28 16:54:31.825 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:54:31.825 V/FA      ( 8871): Connection attempt already in progress
10-28 16:54:31.841 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:54:31.869 D/FA      ( 8871): Connected to remote service
10-28 16:54:31.869 V/FA      ( 8871): Processing queued up service tasks: 3
10-28 16:54:36.871 V/FA      ( 8871): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
10-28 16:56:49.286 W/FA      ( 8871): Invalid screen class length for screen view. Length: 0
10-28 16:56:49.533 V/FA      ( 8871): Logging screen view with name, class: WebViewBottomSheetFragment, com.my.app.main.MainActivity
10-28 16:56:49.560 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:56:49.561 V/FA      ( 8871): Recording user engagement, ms: 137781
10-28 16:56:49.562 D/FA      ( 8871): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
10-28 16:56:49.562 V/FA      ( 8871): Connecting to remote service
10-28 16:56:49.802 D/FA      ( 8871): Connected to remote service
10-28 16:56:49.802 V/FA      ( 8871): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
10-28 16:56:54.804 V/FA      ( 8871): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

As you can see in the logs, the completely differ to what shows up on emulator running on my PC. It logs `Event not sent since app measurement is disabled`, but this should not happen, right? manifest already contains `true` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The error you encountered is returned whenever you're trying to log an event but Firebase Analytics is disabled for your app, so you might need to check if there is a code or configuration somewhere in your project that can cause this. You can use this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android) as a reference for this. Though, it looks like you haven't set the "firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" properly. I think you would need to add value whether you want to permanently disable the collection or not. It is something similar to this -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After initializing your FirebaseAnalytics Classe :

```
private FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;


firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```